# Overlay does not wrapping all the div css

Tags: html, css

I am making overlay effect but problem is overlay div is not wrapping all the divs inside. Overlay background is visible but divs are also visible outside of overlay div.

CSS

```
.overlay_effect {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```css
.overlay_effect {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
}

.columns_sum {
    width: 340px;
    padding: 8px;
}


.price {
    list-style-type: none;
 border: 1px solid #22ADE3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
 overflow: hidden;
}


.price .header {
    background-color: #22ADE3;
 color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
}


.price li {
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: center;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
 border-right: 1px solid #22ADE3;
}


.price .grey_price {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 13px;
 border-right: 1px solid #22ADE3;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #22ADE3;
}


.price .grey_price_right {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 13px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #22ADE3;
}

.coverage_left {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 font-size: 13px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #22ADE3;
}

.avl_text {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: justify !important;
 font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns_sum">
  <div class="overlay_effect">
    <ul class="price">
      <li class="header">Dummy text</li>
      <li class="grey_msg">Dummy text</li>
      <li class="coverage_left">Dummy Text</li>
      <li class="coverage_left">Dummy Text</li>
      <li class="avl_text">Availability: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In rutrum. Praesent dapibus. Phasellus et lorem id felis nonummy placerat. Nulla non lectus sed nisl molestie malesuada.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović I want overlay background should come first and rest all the divs are behind that

Comment: @Jason what do you mean by behind? Can you draw a little sketch maybe?

Comment: z-index works with positioning. For example: position: absolute; z-index: 2. That might be the issue.

Comment: @BirdieGolden I did this but the problem is there are six `columns_sum` div when I used position and z-index overlay background is taking whole browser size not just `columns_sum` size

Comment: @duhaime Something like this [link](http://www.korenlc.com/css-overlay-how-to-create-a-simple-css-overlay/)

Comment: You want the overlay click-through, or click-blocking?

Comment: It looks like folks below will get you going @Jason, happy coding

Answer (score 2):

For an overlay that covers the content of a host element (here: `div.columns_sum`) simply use a pseudo element `::after`:

```
.columns_sum::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

For the positioning to work properly, you need to add `position: relative;` to the element that hosts `::after`:

```
.columns_sum {
  position: relative;
}
```

Otherwise the absolute positioning refers to the closest positioned ancestor element (and if there is none, the `body`).

```css
.columns_sum {
  width: 340px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.columns_sum::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #22ADE3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.price .header {
  background-color: #22ADE3;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.price li {
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  border-right: 1px solid #22ADE3;
}

.price .grey_price {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-right: 1px solid #22ADE3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #22ADE3;
}

.price .grey_price_right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #22ADE3;
}

.coverage_left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #22ADE3;
}

.avl_text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: justify !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns_sum">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Dummy text</li>
    <li class="grey_msg">Dummy text</li>
    <li class="coverage_left">Dummy Text</li>
    <li class="coverage_left">Dummy Text</li>
    <li class="avl_text">Availability: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In rutrum. Praesent dapibus. Phasellus et lorem id felis nonummy placerat. Nulla non lectus sed nisl molestie malesuada.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I got the points and what is the technique to avoid overlay to move outside, like now it's taking some sizes from padding I guess it's not exactly same size of `columns_sum`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the overlay as a child element of the `<div class="columns_sum">` and not the parent of the `ul` list

```
<div class="columns_sum">
    <div class="overlay_effect">
    </div>
    <ul class="price">
      <li class="header">Dummy text</li>
      <li class="grey_msg">Dummy text</li>
      <li class="coverage_left">Dummy Text</li>
      <li class="coverage_left">Dummy Text</li>
      <li class="avl_text">Availability: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In rutrum. Praesent dapibus. Phasellus et lorem id felis nonummy placerat. Nulla non lectus sed nisl molestie malesuada.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

after that put the parent element in the relative position like this

```
.columns_sum {
    position:relative;
    /* and all other code to style this element goes here */
}
```

and the overlay_effect element will be put in the position absolute

```
.overlay_effect {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    z-index: 100;
}
```

this will put the `overlay_effect` element over all other child within the `.columns_sum` element

Comment: Which is exactly what my answer does, but it uses a pseudo element instead.

Comment: with the pseudo element, he can't put any content on the overlay. but with code that I provide, he can put any code inside the overlay element and style it the way he wan't. The pseudo code will be interesting only if he wan't to make some overlay with little opacity to overlap the content of the list without any content.

Comment: I got the points and what is the technique to avoid overlay to move outside, like now it's taking some sizes from padding I guess it's not exactly same size of `columns_sum`

Comment: you can put `* {box-sizing: border-box; }` at the top of you style file, and add `overflow: hidden` on the `.columns_sum` element

Comment: When you make the overlay 100% width and height, because the parent element is in relative position, the overlay will have exactly the same size as his parent. It will not be affecte by their parent padding , because when you put some element in absolute position it goes outside the normal tag flow and not take the place which it should take in the normal flow